# I want to create blog posts to drupal by sending messages through Outlook. Ideas?

Tags: web-services, drupal, outlook, blogs

I think for two options, either to send messages to Drupal with SOAP or XML-RPC or by sending e-mail.

Comment: So? Any news? Did you solved this?

Comment: Still in survey. I'm using the Services module that provides XMLRPC and SOAP services, but i must to tell you that SOAP in Drupal is a nightmare and the lack of documentation in the specific issue makes the things worst. I'm in big disappointment ...

Answer (score 3):

From the description, it looks like [this module](http://drupal.org/project/mmb) does exactly what you want. From the page just linked:

*"Mobile Media Blog allows you to post media via e-mail or mobile phone.
It integrates with Mailhandler and saves the submitted text as node and attaches all files sent with it.
You may choose to use the inline module to display attached files automatically.
The mailalias module allows your users to provide more than on e-mail address for posting."*

**ORIGINAL POSTER SPECIFIED HE/SHE WANTS TO USE WEBSERVICES**

If you want to use webservices to achieve this functionality, then I would suggest to use the [blog_api module](http://drupal.org/node/295) from the Drupal core. This module essentially exposes a number of well-known standards via the xml-rpc interface (MoveableType is the oldest one, but there are also MetaWeblog e Blogger API's in there).

Don't let you be fooled by the name of the module: with *blog_api* you can actually interact with any type of nodes on your site.

As for the reference material, that depends by the kind of API you want to adopt. Here is an [example for the blogger API](http://www.sixapart.com/developers/xmlrpc/blogger_api/).

On a side note: if you go for the blog_api solution, then it might be useful for you to know that there are a number of blogging clients available as desktop applications under nearly any possible operating system. You might well consider using a dedicated software then, rather then an Outlook add-on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to post by mail, check out the [Mailhandler](http://drupal.org/project/mailhandler) module. It doesn't look very popular but it sounds like someone new is taking over maintenance.

If you want to do it via XML-RPC, Drupal has a built-in XML-RPC interface but I don't know about using Outlook for an XML-RPC client.

Answer (score 0):

And of course, yet another module: [Mail2Web](http://drupal.org/project/mail2web). If you are using OG, [Mail to OG](http://drupal.org/project/mail2og) may also be of interest.